# matlab: how to plot multidimensional array

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, geometry-surface

Let's say I have 9 MxN black and white images that are in some way related to one another (i.e. time lapse of some event). What is a way that I can display all of these images on one surface plot?

Assume the MxN matrices only contain 0's and 1's. Assume the images simply contain white lines on a black background (i.e. pixel value == 1 if that pixel is part of a line, 0 otherwise). Assume images are ordered in such a way as to suggest movement progression of line(s) in subsequent images. I want to be able to see a "side-view" (or volumetric representation) of these images which will show the surface that a particular line "carves out" in its movement across the images.

Coding is done in MATLAB. I have looked at `plot` (but it only does 2D plots) and `surf`, which does 3D plots but doesn't work for my MxNx9 matrix of images. I have also tried to experiment with `contourslice`, but not sure what parameters to pass it.

Thanks!

Mariya

Answer (score 2):

Are these images black and white with simple features on a "blank" field, or greyscale, with more dense information?

I can see a couple of approaches.

You can use movie() to display a sequence of images as an animation.

For a static view of sparse, simple data, you could plot each image as a separate layer in a single figure, giving each layer a different color for the foreground, and using AlphaData to make the background transparent so all the steps in the sequenc show through. The gradient of colors corresponds to position in the image sequence. Here's an example.

```
function plotImageSequence

% Made-up test data
nLayers = 9;
x = zeros(100,100,nLayers);
for i = 1:nLayers
    x(20+(3*i),:,i) = 1;
end

% Plot each image as a "layer", indicated by color
figure;
hold on;
for i = 1:nLayers
    layerData = x(:,:,i);
    alphaMask = layerData == 1;
    layerData(logical(layerData)) = i; % So each layer gets its own color
    image('CData',layerData,...
        'AlphaData',alphaMask,...
        'CDataMapping','scaled');
end
hold off
```

Directly showing the path of movement a "line" carves out is hard with raster data, because Matlab won't know which "moved" pixels in two subsequent images are associated with each other. Don't suppose you have underlying vector data for the geometric features in the images? Plot3() might allow you to show their movement, with time as the z axis. Or you could use the regular plot() and some manual fiddling to plot the paths of all the control points or vertexes in the geometric features.

---

EDIT: Here's a variation that uses patch() to draw each pixel as a little polygon floating in space at the Z level of its index in the image sequence. I think this will look more like the "surface" style plots you are asking for. You could fiddle with the FaceAlpha property to make dense plots more legible.

```
function plotImageSequencePatch

% Made-up test data
nLayers = 6;
sz = [50 50];
img = zeros(sz(1),sz(2),nLayers);
for i = 1:nLayers
    img(20+(3*i),:,i) = 1;
end

% Plot each image as a "layer", indicated by color
% With each "pixel" as a separate patch
figure;
set(gca, 'XLim', [0 sz(1)]);
set(gca, 'YLim', [0 sz(2)]);
hold on;
for i = 1:nLayers
    layerData = img(:,:,i);
    [x,y] = find(layerData);  % X,Y of all pixels
    % Reshape in to patch outline
    x = x';
    y = y';
    patch_x = [x; x+1; x+1; x];
    patch_y = [y; y; y+1; y+1];
    patch_z = repmat(i, size(patch_x));

    patch(patch_x, patch_y, patch_z, i);
end
hold off
```

Comment: How many layers does Matlab handle well? I usually simply add RGB values of the different "layers" into a single mxnx3 array.

Comment: I'm looking to have a 3D representation of my 2D images where the 3rd dimension represents time. My images just contain lines (so only possible matrix values are 0 and 1). My ultimate goal is to be able to track a particular line across images and determine its path (or which image it originated from). I was hoping to use a "neighboring pixels" approach to see if an image in the sequence has the same line within an appropriate neighborhood. But first I'd like to visualize my data. So plot each MxN image, where one image is a progression of the previous over time. Thus obtaining a surface plot.

Comment: @Jonas: Depends on plot size and memory; a few dozen before hitting memory problems for plots around 500x500 in 2 GB RAM. The MxNx3 form should work fine as well; the user will just have to calculate absolute color values, where the MxNx1 form will automatically normalize in to the figure's color map.

Comment: @Myx: As far as I can tell, none of the Matlab plots quite work that way. Most of the stuff that plots into 3 dimensions works on data series or lines, not raster data. That is, it presumes you already know the point relationships. The surface() function would let you draw each image as a plane and get them as layers in the "time" 3rd dimension. But I couldn't figure out how to get it to do transparency on it. You could also plot it by using patch() to draw each individual "on" pixel as a polygon in 3-D space. I'll see if I can figure one of those out.

Comment: @Myx: The patch() approach turns out to be pretty easy, if I understand what you're looking for. See edit to my original answer.